# Filtrar DatagridView con ComboBox SelectValue

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo un formulario con un combobox y un datagridview.

Tengo dos sp en mi base de datos SqlServer.

El primer sp carga los datos al ComboBox, con el DisplayMember de la segunda columna del sp tipo texto, y en el ValueMember tengo el Id de mi sp.

La carga de datos al ComboBox funciona bien, con lo que tengo problemas es para pasar los datos del Id seleccionado en el combobox al dgv el segundo sp que tengo recibe un parámetro para aplicar el filtro, pero para filtrar el dgv estoy usando el SelectIndex y este me toma del 0,1,2 y en mi base de datos tengo los Ids 1,2,3 hice unas pruebas con el MessageBox y ver que es lo que estoy seleccionado con esto pude validar lo que comente anteriormente.

Entonces como puedo tomar el SelectValue del combobox para filtrar mi dgv, disculpen por el código desordenado o mal estructurado pero estoy realizando los pininos en C#.
Yo creo que el error es solo el SelectIndex salvo su mejor opinión.

```
 //Carga de datos al combo box desde el sp
    private void FormStartRobot_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ListaNom", cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Idaplicacion";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "aplicacion";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

            cnx.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }


private DataTable mostrarActividades(int IdAplicacion)
    {
        cnx.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MuestraListaAplicaciones", cnx);
        var name = new SqlParameter("@idApp", IdAplicacion);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idApp", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@idApp"].Value = IdAplicacion;
        SqlDataReader read  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        {
            if(read.HasRows)
            {
                dt.Load(read);
            }
            cnx.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }


private DataTable listaActividades(int Idaplicacion)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = mostrarActividades(Idaplicacion);

        return dt;
    }

private void cargaDGV()
    {
        //Que seleccione el IdAplicacion del combobox
        dataGridView1.DataSource = listaActividades(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }

private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != 0)
                cargaDGV();


            //Pruebas MessageBox para ver la seleccion del combo
            var selval = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            var selindex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

            int v1 = Convert.ToInt32(selval);
            MessageBox.Show((v1).ToString());

            int v2 = Convert.ToInt32(selindex);
            MessageBox.Show((v2).ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + error.Message);
        }
    }
```

Gracias anticipadamente.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución, no se si es la mejor pero quedo así:

```
private void cargaDGV()
    {
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("MuestraListaAplicaciones", cnx);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idApp", comboBox1.SelectedValue);

        da.Fill(dt);

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
                cargaDGV();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo cargar el dgv: " + error.Message);
        }
    }
```